# Como definir um listStore para renderizar uma barra de progresso no gtk2?

Tags: c, treeview, gtk

Eu estou procurando um exemplo para criar um listStore (para usar em um treeView) que pode conter um campo do tipo barra de progresso.

Eu estou escrevendo em C (não em c++) e usando gtk2 no meu código:

`store=gtk_liststore_new(3,G_TYPE_STRING,G_TYPE_INT, G_TYPE???);`

Então o que é o `G_TYPE`? Eu o uso para dizer para o listStore que é uma barra de progresso?